# 設定ファイルの文法エラーをチェックしてから、Nginx再起動

Tags: centos, bash, nginx, shellscript

**「nginx -t」が正しかった場合のみ、「systemctl restart nginx.service」実行したいのですが、下記で合っていますか？**

```
$ sudo nginx -t && systemctl restart nginx.service
```

---

**下記は、上記と何が違うのですか？**
・それぞれ長所短所があれば教えてください

```
sudo sh -c 'nginx -t && systemctl restart nginx.service'
```

・何れも、幾つでも連結可ですか？

```
$ sudo コマンド && コマンド || コマンド || コマンド
$ sudo sh -c 'コマンド && コマンド || コマンド || コマンド'
```

---

**環境**
・CentOS7
・Nginx

Comment: Markdownの「引用」は基本的にプレーンなテキスト向けです。コマンド文字列は「コードハイライト」を使用した方が見やすく表示されます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

試してみればすぐにわかることだとは思いますが、

`$ sudo nginx -t && systemctl restart nginx.service`

`nginx`は管理者権限で実行され、それが成功すると、`systemctl`が現在のユーザの権限で実行されます。これが期待通りかどうかはわかりません。`sudo`の引数は`&&`の直前までです。

`sudo sh -c 'nginx -t && systemctl restart nginx.service'`

`sh`が管理者権限で実行されるので、その中で実行される`nginx`も`systemctl`も管理者権限で実行されます。行末まですべてが`sudo`の引数です。